# tcp client does not throw error while connecting to localhost if no server is ready

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I tried to encapsulate all networking functionalities for my program inside a "SimpleClient" class, which exposes this interface inside the .hpp file:

```
class SimpleClient{
    //private
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> signal_socket; 
    protected: 
        boost::asio::io_context my_context;
        ClientState state; //0: Ready to be used, not connected,  -1: error, 1: Connected/active, 
    public: 
       SimpleClient();
       virtual bool connect(const char* ip_address);
       virtual void disconnect();
       virtual bool sendMessage(const char* msg, int length);
       virtual int getResponse( char* msg, int length, int timeout);
       virtual int getSignalData( char* msg, int length);
       virtual ClientState getState();
};
```

While testing the connect method I noticed that even if no server was waiting on localhost on port 8887, the connect did not throw an error. How can I check that the socket is connected for real?

Here the methods that I implemented and a small example that reproduces my behavior, using boost.test:

```
SimpleClient::SimpleClient() : my_context() {
    signal_socket.reset();
    state = ClientState::CL_UNCON;
}

bool SimpleClient::connect(const char* ip_address) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    if (signal_socket != NULL && signal_socket->is_open() )
        return true;
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint signal_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(ip_address), 8887);
        signal_socket.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(my_context));
        signal_socket->connect(signal_endpoint, ec);
        if(ec) {
            std::cout<<ec.message()<<" "<<ec.value()<<std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    } catch(const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
        std::cout<<ex.code()<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cout<<signal_socket<<std::endl;
    state = ClientState::CL_READY;
    return true;
}
```

Here is the test program:

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN 
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include "SimpleClient.hpp"

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <string.h>

#define TARGET_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define BAD_IP "128.0.0.1"


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(connection_test)  {
    bool ret;
    std::cout<<"Connect to WRONG address"<<std::endl;
    SimpleClient* ut = new SimpleClient();
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(ut->getState(), ClientState::CL_UNCON);
    ret = ut->connect(BAD_IP);
    BOOST_CHECK(!ret);
    std::cout<<"Connect to RIGHT address"<<std::endl;
    ret = ut->connect(TARGET_IP);
    BOOST_CHECK(ret);
    ut->disconnect();
    try{
        delete ut;
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Please don't spam connections to stranger's computers as part of random testing.

Comment: Have you tried running your program under a syscall monitoring tool such as strace to see if the connect actually fails?

Comment: thanks a lot, i found the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem was inside my connect method, obviously. The first call to the connect inside my test failed, but it did not close the socket, so the second call automatically returned true  without performing any operation.

**TLDR**: in case of failure, connect does not close the socket, and any call to is_open() will return 'true', call manually close() method on the socket in case of error.

```
bool SimpleClient::connect(const char* ip_address) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    if (signal_socket != NULL && signal_socket->is_open() )
        return true;
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint signal_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(ip_address), 8887);
        signal_socket.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(my_context));
        signal_socket->connect(signal_endpoint, ec);
        if(ec) {
            std::cout<<ec.message()<<" "<<ec.value()<<std::endl;
            signal_socket->close();
            signal_socket.reset();
            return false;
        }
    } catch(const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
        std::cout<<ex.code()<<std::endl;
        signal_socket->close();
        signal_socket.reset();
        return false;
    }
    std::cout<<signal_socket<<std::endl;
    state = ClientState::CL_READY;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively adjust the control flow so that the socket isn't used after an error. This is the more natural approach. Often checking "is_open" is not what you're after anyways (e.g. it won't be able to detect when the remote end closed a connection). +1 for answering your own question though!